# Use array destructuring / unsure how to

Tags: ecmascript-6

I'm getting a destructure lint error and, more broadly, trying to understand hot destructure different types of objects.

I'm not sure why this needs to be destructured, or what the destructured syntax would be:

`let displayUrl = websiteUrl.split('/')[0];`

Comment: there is no destructuring syntax in that code snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the syntax to destructure an array.

```
let [displayUrl] = websiteUrl.split('/');
```

Or if you are expecting more parts after splitting the string:

```
let [part1, part2, part3] = websiteUrl.split('/');
```

Using destructuring synxtax is useful for keeping the code shorter when there are multiple parts that needs to be assigned to variables. for example:

Instead of writing as

```
const firstElem = elements[0];
const secondElem = elements[1];
const thirdElem = elements[2];
const fourthElem = elements[3];
```

Using destructing syntax, you can achieve the same result by

```
const [firstElem, secondElem, thirdElem, fourthElem] = elements;
```

In your case where there is only element, I don't think there is any difference.

Comment: Thank you kindly Wei. Why does the lint error go away if I change it to a const instead of let?

Comment: see https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/278653. 
You can also read more about the eslint for prefer const over let here: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-const